# No such file or directory but file png exists

Tags: bash

I'm newbie of Ubuntu.
This command was used for the `xcowsay` config file, and when I used the `source` command, it was an error:
`-bash: alt-image=/home/abc/Documents/b_st_159.png: No such file or directory`,
Tested with this command `alt-image=$HOME/Documents/b_st_159.png` in terminal, the error was same, but the file was already exists at this directory: `$HOME/Documents/b_st_159.png` when checking by using `ls -la ~/Documents`, the file has shown as green line like this:
`-rwxr-xr-x  1 abc  abc   471304 May 15 22:48  b_st_159.png`
I was also using `file` command and it results file exits as shown below:\

```
$ file b_st_159.png
b_st_159.png: PNG image data, 1386 x 640, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

So how to fix this error? [image: file exists image] 
as same as I run in terminal
P/s: I was also find in google but result is for executable file.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by typing `alt-image=$HOME/Documents/b_st_159.png`in the terminal? First let us know what you really want to achieve. Edit your question to clarify.

Comment: This command was used for the `xcowsay` config file, and when I used the `source` command, it was an error as same as I run in terminal.

Comment: Use "edit" to add any relevant information and clarification to your question. A well understood question is more likely to attract a well written and topical answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to run the `source` command here

If you have the config file in the correct location, on execution of the `xcowsay` command it will read the config in
To find where the correct location for the xcowsay config file location is check here
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man6/xcowsay.6.html

> xcowsay reads a configuration file on startup.  The configuration file can  be  stored  in
> the   XDG   compliant   location   $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/xcowsayrc   (which   will  default  to
> $HOME/.config/xcowsayrc)  or  in  your  home  directory  at  $HOME/.xcowsayrc.    If   the
> --config=FILE  command  line  option  is passed FILE will be processed after your personal
> configuration file.

A note on what is happening here,
The source command executes command from a text file but there are not necessarily bash command
Running `source bash.rc` works because everything in this file can be executed in a bash terminal

Comment: Thank you for comments. As i checked the [xcowsay page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man6/xcowsay.6.html), if i run `fortune | xcowsay --image=/home/abc/Documents/b_st_159.png`, it had no such problem, happily open the file``b_st_159.png` as cow-replace. But when I use `sudo nano $HOME/.config/xcowsayrc`, then add `alt-image=/home/abc/Documents/b_st_159.png`, save and re-run, its shown error `Invalid option 'alt-image'`, and can be get no such file when run the `source $HOME/.config/xcowsayrc , its show error no such file or directory`.

Comment: The setting in the config should be `alt_image=/home/abc/Documents/b_st_159.png` rather than `alt-image`

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear.
I suggest you

1. Show the exact `xcowsay` command you used, if any.
2. Show the exact `source` command you used.
3. Show the complete contents of your `xcowsay` config file.

In the meantime, perhaps using `alt_image` instead of `alt-image` works:

> ```
> --image=file
>      Use a different image instead of the cow. The corresponding config 
>      file option is alt_image.
> ```

I tried it and it works.